# ReactJS, NodeJS, Is it a safe to use a single use password for my app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, authentication

I'm creating a web app where users will only visit occasionally, so I'm trying to prevent the users from having to remember a password.

Would it be secure to have a flow like this.

- Enter email (or phone number)
- Get temporary password (create the password on the backend, save to mongoDB)
- User enters temporary password (Validating against password in database and deleting and returning a token if matched)
- let the user authenticate through token.

Comment: Why not let them try to remember the password and then use this flow if they forget? It seems more inconvenient to have to leave the site, wait for an email, come back and paste it in; than to just remember it or have the browser remember it. Security-wise its probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

This question is opinionated so it will likely get closed... but short story, that’s totally fine. This is how Medium does it. Make sure the temporary passwords are encrypted in your database though as they are as sensitive as real passwords.